# How do I Remove text before a space in java?

Tags: java, string

```
String str = "hello world";
int spacePos = str.indexOf(" ");
if (spacePos > 0) {
    String youString = str.substring(0, spacePos - 1);
    System.out.println(youString);
}
```

I want *"world"* as a result. How do I get this result?

Comment: You seems to know that you have to use `substring` method. What is the problem? What do you think `str .substring(0, spacePos - 1);` should return and why?

Comment: `str.substring(spacePos + 1);`

Comment: Debug your code. The solution is trivial.

Comment: You could also use `split` which might be easier and more readable `System.out.println(str.split(" ")[1]);`

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA No. He's trying to remove all the characters before a space. `str = str.split(" ")[1];` Try it see if it works...

Comment: Is this April's fool? I think its too late.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA what if he used a for loop? In the OP's example he is just trying to get the second word of 2 words...If the OP has other scenarios in mind then he can try something else like `for loop` or `substring` or `regex`...

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA no read between the lines.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA if all the OP needs to do is get the second of 2 words my solution is a lot cleaner, easier, and more readable.  If you notice I didn't post an answer I posted it in the comments section.  If the OP needs something different he is free to do whatever he likes.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA "his algorithm is only correct with `substring`" this can be accomplished using `regex`.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`substring(startIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) form of `substring` method.
Find the index of the space (' '), pass the *result + 1* to the `substring` method and it will output the string starting from that position to the end. Like follows:

```
String str = "hello world";
String youString = str.substring(str.indexOf(' ') + 1);
System.out.println(youString);
```

Comment: You should explain your solution, simply pasting code is an example of a poor quality answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should first check if your string contains a space, that way you also don't have to check if `index > 0`.

```
String str = "hello world";
if (!str.contains(" ")){
    //Stop, handle this situation, throw an exception, whatever you want 
    //I'm just returning an empty string for simplicity now.
    return "";
}

int spacePos = str.indexOf(" ");
String suffix = str.substring(spacePos + 1, str.length()); //Gets the 'world' part
```

Answer (score 0):

One way, though there are many others, you could use string.split(\s) which I BELIEVE splits the string anywhere it finds the specified character (in this case space) and stores the substrings in an array. Then you could just grab the index you want, in this case the second element so array[1]